# Ext-JS 4.0: ViewPort autoscroll and can't get value of fields

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm writing a simple application using EXT-JS 4.0 for creating quick surveys. The questions and their answering options are contained and transferred through a JSON object which is then dynamically displayed. Each question has a text displayed using a DisplayField instance (`xtype: 'displayfield'`) and resides, along with the answering options, in a `Ext.form.Panel` instance. Depending on the JSON object, answering might be through free text (using a `TextAreaField`), a choice 1-of-many (using radio buttons), or many-of-many (using check boxes).

After decoding the JSON object, I iterate through the questions with a regular `for` loop to dynamically create the necessary widgets (holding panel, question text, text area, check boxes, and radio buttons, and a submit button for testing). After the loop, I add these panels to a Container with `layout: 'vbox'` and finally add the container to a viewport with `layout: 'fit'`.

This is the format of the JSON object to display the questions:

```
{questions: [{
    question:'Do you know it?',
    comment: 'no',
    multiple: [],
    single: ['yes','no']
  }, {
    question:'In which seasons do you use it (add your comment with your selection)?',
    comment: 'yes',
    multiple: ['Winter','Spring','Summer','Fall'],
    single: []
  }
]}
```

And there is my code:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    // Decode the received JSON object..
    var jsonObj = Ext.JSON.decode(jsonObjStr);

    // Array to hold the to-be-created panels for rendering in global container..
    var panels = new Array();

    for (i = 1; i <= jsonObj.questions.length; i++) {
        // Create a Panel to contain the question..
        var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            id: 'panel' + toString(i),
            frame: false,
            border: true,
            title: 'Question ' + i,
            width: '75%',
            margin: '10 0 0 0',
            fieldDefaults: {
                labelAlign: 'left',
                labelWidth: 90,
                buttonAlign: 'center',
                anchor: '100%'
            }
        });

        // Add the question text first..
        var questionText = {
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            name: 'questionTextTf' + i,
            value: '<b>' + jsonObj.questions[i - 1].question + '</b>'
        };
        formPanel.add(questionText);

        // Add the check boxes for many-of-many answers..
        var checkBoxes = new Array();
        for (imultiple = 0; imultiple < jsonObj.questions[i - 1].multiple.length; imultiple++) {
            var itemChk = {
                name: 'cb' + i,
                id: 'cb' + toString(i) + '-' + toString(imultiple),
                boxLabel: jsonObj.questions[i - 1].multiple[imultiple]
            };
            checkBoxes.push(itemChk);
        }
        if (jsonObj.questions[i - 1].multiple.length > 0) {
            var multipleFieldContainer = {
                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                name: 'multipleContainer' + i,
                id: 'multipleContainer' + toString(i),
                fieldLabel: 'Select all that match',
                items: checkBoxes
            };
            formPanel.add(multipleFieldContainer);
        }

        // Add the radio buttons for one-of-many answers..
        var radioBoxes = new Array();
        for (isingle = 0; isingle < jsonObj.questions[i - 1].single.length; isingle++) {
            var itemRdb = {
                name: 'rb' + i,
                id: 'rb' + toString(i) + '-' + toString(isingle),
                boxLabel: jsonObj.questions[i - 1].single[isingle]
            };
            radioBoxes.push(itemRdb);
        }
        if (jsonObj.questions[i - 1].single.length > 0) {
            var singleFieldContainer = {
                xtype: 'radiogroup',
                name: 'singleContainer' + i,
                id: 'singleContainer' + toString(i),
                fieldLabel: 'Select one',
                items: radioBoxes
            };
            formPanel.add(singleFieldContainer);
        }

        // Add the text area field for free text comments..
        if (jsonObj.questions[i - 1].comment == 'yes') {
            var commentArea = {
                xtype: 'textareafield',
                name: 'commentTa' + i,
                id: 'commentsTa' + toString(i),
                fieldLabel: 'Comment'
            };
            formPanel.add(commentArea);
        }

        // Add the submit button for each question (for testing)..
        var sendButton = {
            xtype: 'button',
            name: 'submitBtn' + i,
            id: 'submitBtn' + toString(i),
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: function () {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Info', Ext.getCmp('commentsTa' + toString(i)).getId() + ': ' + Ext.getCmp('commentsTa' + toString(i)).getValue());
            }
        };
        formPanel.add(sendButton);

        // Add panel to array of panels for later rendering..
        panels.push(formPanel);
    }

    // Create the global container to contain all the created panels..
    var mainContainer = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
        html: 'First Set of Preliminary Questions: <br>',
        //renderTo: 'form-ct1',
        style: {
            borderColor: '#000000',
            borderStyle: 'solid',
            borderWidth: '2px'
        },
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'center'
        },
        items: panels
    });

    // Create a viewport to render the global container to fill the body region of the page..
    var viewport = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: mainContainer,
        autoScroll: true
    });
});
```

**Now the problems are:**

1. If there are too many panels to be displayed on the page, the autoscroll of the viewport doesn't cover all the subsequent panels. That is, I can't see all of them!
2. If I execute the code above with the id of the widgets set according to the following pattern, for example `id: 'commentsTa'+toString(i)`, only the last widget of each type is displayed. This is because they all seem to take the same value since the expression `toString(i)` turns out to be interpreted as `[object DOMWindow]`. If I don't use the `toString()` then the `id` is not recognised at all and can't use the `Ext.getCmp()` method.

I'd really appreciate your help with these issues!

Comment: I managed to solve the second issue!! The problem seems to be in the toString() function. All I needed to do is declaring a variable and use another way to convert numbers to strings (e.g. var x=1+' ' then id: 'commentsTa'+x) and it works like a charm for id and itemId configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, vertical scroll bars are not created for a container with a `vBox` layout. The aim of such a layout is to keep all the contained elements within the containing box. Removing this layout and using the default one would solve this problem.

As for the second problem:
1- To convert from int to String then:

```
var myInt=5;
var myString=myInt+'';
```

2- To convert from String to int then:

```
var myInt=parseInt(new String("5"));
```